# Is it possible to make Xcode auto complete to act like visual assist?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autocomplete

I am using Xcode 6.1 on Yosemite, writing IOS apps using swift.

For example:

If I type:

```
myClass.st
```

I was hoping the editor to show me this:

```
myClass.SetTitle()
```

but the reality is not what I had expected.
the editor says no match. In case of visual assist or Sublime Text, "st" mathes "SetTitle"

Sometimes people only remember a few keywords of the long variable name, rather than the full name from the very beginning.

Is is possible to solve this issue by some plugins?

Thank you

Comment: @AnnaDickinson tried, not working, says no completion

Comment: May be myClass Does't have property name SetTitle?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni it has, but i have to type myClass.Set

Comment: did you restart everything?

Comment: The completion is based on the letters you type in. So if your class doesn't have properties or method names starting with `st` there is nothing to complete.

Comment: @zisoft myClass.SetTitle exists, but I want "st" to match "SetTitle"

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer to this.
The plugin is called
FuzzyAutocompletePlugin
Written by GitHub.com/chemo